# D3js chaining transition using .call

Tags: d3.js

I want to have a function that handles every transition part, and to be able to chain it using `.call`:

```
it
    .attr //state 1
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr //state 2
```

to

```
function move(it){
    return it.transition().duration(1000)
}


it
    .attr //state 1
    .transition()
    .call move
    .attr //state 2
```

I want to aggregate all transition within one function, and making it conditional. Example below:

```
var w = 960;
var h = 500;
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);



var animation = true;


function runAnimation(it){ // this doesn't work, it will just skip the animation
    if(animation){
        return it.transition()
            .duration(1000);
    }
    else{
        return it;
    }
}

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", w / 2)
    .attr("cy", h / 2)
    .attr("r", 2)
    .call(runAnimation)
    .attr("cx", 50)
```

I am aware that I can do:

```
function runAnimation2(it, nextStep){
    if(animation){
        return it.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .call(nextStep)
    }
    else{
        return it;
    }
}

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", w / 2)
    .attr("cy", h / 2 + 10)
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .call(runAnimation2, function(it){ it.attr("cx", 50)})
```

Yet I feel it breaks the "flow".

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#call):

> The call operator always returns the current selection, regardless of the return value of the specified function.

This is why your first code fragment will not work. You have to use something like the second fragment.